# Implement Ajax calls via XMPP messages

Tags: ajax, apache2, xmpp

I have a website where users are connected with XMPP server (ejabberd). I want to replace my ajax calls with xmpp messages to reduce the load on apache server.

ie

a replace for ajax call, which works on following ideas

1. Send a XMPP message
2. Add a handler which is fired when the data for the specific ajax request is answered through a message

Is there a wrapper to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/).

It's a pretty powerful JavaScript library for doing XMPP in the browser.

Comment: We use strophe.js itself. What I am looking for is a wrapper to migrate my ajax calls to xmpp messages. – w2lame 21 mins ago